# How do I print string backward each letter on separate line, Using while loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stuck at Excercise problem where I have to print Word "Banana" in reversed each letter on a separate line.

Below is my code:-

```
  fruit = "BANANA"
  index = -1
  while len(fruit) > index:
     letter = fruit[index]
     print(letter)
     index = index -1
```

Output:-

```
A

N

A

N

A

B
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Banana.py", line 4, in

```
letter = fruit[index]
```

> IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create an index. In fact, it makes the code less efficient and more prone to bugs (as you noticed). Instead You can reverse your string using `[::-1]`, and just iterate through it, because iterating through a string means going through each individual character:

```
fruit = "BANANA"

for letter in fruit[::-1]:
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the `print()`-command ([Doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)) command to do all that for you:

```
print(*("BANANA"[::-1]), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
A
N
A
N
A
B
```

It reverses the string, use `*` to seperate the string into its chars and applies `'\n'` as seperator between any 2 elements printed.